# PyQt5 push button method called from separate python file

Tags: pyqt5

This is my **mainWindow.py**, here I have a only a push button:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to create a separate file **eventHandler.py**, where I can write `pushButton` calle method.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from mainWindow import *

self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.function1)

def function1(self):                                             
        print("function called")
```

Can anyone tell me how I can initialize classes and write it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an inappropriate approach, eventHandler must be a library that is used by mainWindow, and not vice versa.

**main.py**

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

from mainWindow import Ui_MainWindow

from eventHandler import function1

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(function1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**eventHandler.py**

```py
def function1():                                
    print("function called")
```

Comment: okay thanks. actually my main.py is generated from .ui file . so if i changed the ui file than main.py will changed and  than  i have to re write this self.pushButton.clicked.connect(function1) again.

Comment: @DhurjatiRiyanBorah This solution does not modify `mainWindow.py`. `main.py` is a separate file that imports `Ui_MainWindow` from the original version of `mainWindow.py`.

Comment: @DhurjatiRiyanBorah  according to your code the file generated by pyuic is mainWindow.py. and since my solution does not modify mainWindow.py, therefore, I did not indicate anything in my answer.