# pyqt5 button click not working from my second window

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5

i am stuck in call function from pushButton.
in my project:

1. **app.py**, which is the main file to run the project.
2. **ui_mainWindow.py** is the file consist of tab widget.
3. **Account.py** is the converted file from account.ui
4. **main_Account.py** is the file where i import Account.py file.
5. **account_handler.py** is  the file where consist of functions.

now when i run my project by running app.py ,it will show all contents of ui_mainWindow.py .now if i choose account tab from tabwidget than it will show all contents of mainAccount.py. now if i hit a button from mainAccount.py than function will be call from account_handler.py.

everything working fine but while i hut pushButton nothin happen.

this is my previous post : [PyQt5 push button method called from separate python file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60802690/pyqt5-push-button-method-called-from-separate-python-file) ,
i follow this separately and this working fine, but in my project samecode not working. can anyone tell me where i am wrong!

**app.py**

```
from importlib import reload
import PyQt5.QtCore as QtCore
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
import sys
import files.interfaces.ui_mainWindow

import files.interfaces.dashboard
reload(files.interfaces.dashboard)

import files.main_Interfaces.mainAccount
reload(files.main_Interfaces.mainAccount)

import files.interfaces.account2
reload(files.interfaces.account2)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow, files.interfaces.ui_mainWindow.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        # Base class
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.ui = files.interfaces.ui_mainWindow.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("PORTFOLIO ACCOUNTING")

        # import tab1
        self.TabWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        ui = files.interfaces.dashboard2.Ui_Form()
        ui.setupUi(self.TabWidget)
        self.ui.tabWidget.insertTab(0, self.TabWidget, "Dashboard")

        # import tab2
        self.TabWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        ui = files.main_Interfaces.mainAccount.MainWindow()
        ui.setupUi(self.TabWidget)
        self.ui.tabWidget.insertTab(1, self.TabWidget, "Account")

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName("Portfolio Accounting")
    application = MainWindow()
    application.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**main_Account.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from files.interfaces.account import Ui_Form
from event_handler.account_EventHndler import function2

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(function1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**account_handler.py**

```
def function1():                                
    print("function called")
```

Comment: provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc, thank you. i will follow all.
any solution for my above problem?

Answer (score 0):

You code is a bit confusing since you use the same class names in different modules and there is an inconsistencies between the names of the modules you are importing and the names of the .py files you provided but I'm assuming that `files.main_Interfaces.mainAccount.MainWindow` refers to `mainWindow` in `main_Account.py`. In that case, in `app.MainWindow.__init__` tab2 should probably be something like

```
# import tab2
self.TabWidget = files.main_Interfaces.mainAccount.MainWindow()
self.ui.tabWidget.insertTab(1, self.TabWidget, "Account")
```